# How to initialise TinyMCE from element

Tags: knockout.js, tinymce, tinymce-4

The documentation states that you initialise tinymce like so:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#mytextarea'
  });
```

However, I wish to do this from within a binding extensions in knockout where I have access to the element.

As such I would like to be able to do the following:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.tinymce = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        $(element).tinymce();
        return ko.bindingHandlers.textInput.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings);
    }
}
```

This is how existing binding extensions work that I have found on the web however for me I am getting `tinymce is not a function` and wonder if the API has changed forcing you to use selectors.

Is that true?

Comment: I should probably note that the former works fine for me.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/michaelpapworth/tinymce-knockout-binding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API has not changed. However, you are using the wrong dependencies. In order to use jQuery with tinyMCE you need to use the **following dependencies** in this **exact** order:

1. http://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.jquery.min.js
2. https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js

Take a look at [this working example.](http://codepen.io/ricardobrandao/pen/advrVj/)

```
var settings = {
    height: 500,
    plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
        'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
        'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code'
    ],
    toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
    content_css: [
        '//fast.fonts.net/cssapi/e6dc9b99-64fe-4292-ad98-6974f93cd2a2.css',
        '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
    ]
};

ko.bindingHandlers.tinymce = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        $(element).tinymce(settings);
        return ko.bindingHandlers.textInput.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings();
```

Comment: Thank you, seems I was including the `tinymce.jquery.js` file and the `tinymce.js` file. I needed the `jquery.tinymce,js` file instead. Strangely the file ordering did not seem to make a difference for me and the codepen example seems to be in a different order than order you mentioned here. But no worries, sorted now. Many thanks.

Comment: The settings were also important, without them there were no errors but nothing was rendered.